# What is the difference between -lt and < in shell?

Tags: shell, sh

I'm studying shell scripting and don't understand the difference between `-eq` and `==`, `-lt` and `<`, `-gt` and `>`, so on.

I'm trying to write a while loop printing out from 0 to 9

```
num=0
while [ $num -lt 10 ]; do
   echo "$num"
   ((num++))
done
```

This code works but when I change `-lt` to `<`, it says No such file or directory.

```
num=0
while [ $num < 10 ]; do
   echo "$num"
   ((num++))
done
```

What is the issue with `<` here? Do I always have to go for `-lt` in while loops? Is there a general way to do while loops? Appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shell scripting has been always different when it comes to syntax.

so when you say `-lt` it means less than (<).so when you write your code it works totally fine

```
while [ $num -lt 10 ]; do
   echo "$num"
   ((num++))
done
```

But when you use `<` this in the shell script it is used to read input from file or directory. So here in your case, it will search for the name of the file which is inside the `$num` variable

**In simple words**

1. `-lt` is Less than which is used for condition checking
2. `<` is used for Reading input from the files.

Comment: That's not what < means

Comment: The statement `[ $num < 10 ]` is just syntactic sugar for the command `test $num < 10`, which means: Run the command `test` with one parameter (the content of the shell variable `num`), and associate the standard input of this invocation with a file named `10`. Since you don't have a file of this name, you get the error.  You would get the same error by writing, i.e. `: <10`.

Comment: There are implementations (`bash`'s built-in `test`, e.g.) which allow `<` for string comparison. It still needs to be escaped to avoid being parsed as a redirection operator, though: `if [ bar \< foo ]; then echo "bar comes before foo alphabetically"; fi`.

Answer (score 2):

In commandline 
**<** means read input from file

for example 
**grep "myname" < data.txt**

also,
 **>**  redirect output to a file

for example **ls > lists.txt**

when executing **$num < 10** 
it checking for a file named 10

Answer (score 0):

The command `[` specifies that `-lt` should be used to compare two integers. Expecting `<` to do anything useful is simply wishful.

Coincidentally, the character `<` is a metacharacter in bash used for [input redirection](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0070.php). The error you get is due to the file `10` not existing in your cwd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '<' with double parentheses (integers) or curly brace (strings)

```
num=0
while (( $num < 10 )); do
    echo "$num"
    ((num++))
done
```

and for strings

```
str="a"
while [[ $str < "aaaaa" ]]; do
    echo "$str"
    str+="a"
done
```